# Python and OpenCV - Why a processed with OpenCV cropped image can still effect the original image?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, crop, opencv3.0

I am using Python and OpenCV 3 for image processing.

So, I have cropped an image like this:

```
image = cv2.imread('image_path')
cropped = image[0:100, 0:100]
```

When I use the `cropped` as an argument to a function, that is I detect the edges in the `cropped`, apply Hough Transformation and then make a line on it, I noticed that the same line is also drawn to the original `image`. Why is that?
Is it mean the `cropped` image is somehow still connected to the original `image`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opencv image data sliced is a reference with different geometry and not a copy. They are numpy arrays. From the numpy docs at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing :

> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original
>   array.

To force it to be a copy, use `cropped=np.array(image, copy=True)[0:100, 0:100]`.

Comment: Thanks! Straightforward, very easy to understand explanation!